# Error when pushing int to vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've got error when I'm pushing integer to vector: `member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union`. What happened, here is my mistake?

```
int angles;
cin >> angles;

int i = 0;
while (i < angles) {
  string s;
  cin >> s;

  vector<int> ints;
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    ints[i].push_back( s[j] - '0' );
  }

  i++;
}
```

Comment: Just do `ints.push_back( s[j] - '0' );`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data your trying to load from the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ints[i].push_back( s[j] - '0' );` is incorrect syntax.

It should read `ints.push_back( s[j] - '0' );`. What you currently try to do is call the `push_back` command on an `int`, which results in the error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are trying to do this:

```
void loadAngles() {
   size_t angles;
   cin >> angles;
   vector< vector<int> > ints(angles);
   for (int i=0; i<angles; ++i) {
      string s;
      cin >> s;
      const char* str = s.c_str();
      for (size_t j=0; j<2; ++j) {
     ints[i].push_back( str[j] - '0' );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The conversion to `const char*` that you added is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @molbdnilo string.c_str() returns const char* so, yeah it is necessary.

Comment: @molbdnilo getting the internal character string using c_str and then referring to that is a matter of preference. You might think it's unnecessary, I believe it is more expressive. I also created a vector of vector "ints" (therefore ints[i] is no longer a bug) as I believe this is what OP was actually trying to do .